# My Android application won't load (I see only the home screen)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

After debugging my application, my emulator starts up (Using API 8), I see the "Android" splash screen(as it loads). Then, unlocking and I see the home screen, but my app never loads.

What's the problem? What am I doing wrong? (I'm using Eclipse Juno IDE).

Comment: I haven't edited the startup code

Comment: @AnuragRamdasan Forgot to tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just restart Eclipse or check the Console for any errors or check your run configurations. I've faced a similar issue in the past and doing the three things above has usually solved the issue for me.

Comment: Nothing happens, still I've done what you told but same issue.

Comment: I've found another solution, but I'll accept yours anyways, thanks!